# What are these components in green white and orange colour on this PCB?

Tags: passive-components

[image]Got curious about these components because they seem very different from what I've used till now.

Comment: It would help if you added the photo!

Comment: thank you for reply, I have added the image please take a look at it.

Comment: Someone appears to have removed identifying markings from the green components? They're probably capacitors. The orange ones are definitely capacitors. The white "TIC 0E1" look like power resistors.

Comment: Can you read any of the values of the green components or even get a picture of where it's scratched off? They're probably capacitors but other components do come in that package type.

Comment: They are totally scratched, not readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The white components are ceramic power resistors. They are rated at 5W and have a resistance of 0.1 Ohms. They're sometimes used as current shunts in lower power applications.

The green components are most likely capacitors, usually in this package they're known as *film capacitors*. As pjc50 mentions, the values seem to be scratched off (odd thing to do to a capacitor). This suggests they might not be a capacitor, RC snubbers also come in this package type as well as other components.

The orange components are without doubt capacitors.

Comment: These green components are on the PCB of an therapeutic ultrasound generator. May be they didn't wish other people to repair it.

Comment: @user134265 It's not like you can desolder it and measure the capacitance... oh wait....